# Relational Database design for HAS_MANY with a primary BELONGS_TO

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I'm working in MySQL but this is a general relational database enquiry.

We have a blog CMS where users can change the URL of a blog after go live and we want to 301 any old blog URL to the new one.

I am torn between the two following table options (all fields NOT NULL):

**Option 1 - HAS_MANY with primary flag**

- url

  - id (PK)
  - url (UNIQUE)
  - blog_id (FK to blog - id)
  - is_primary (0 or 1)
- blog

  - id (PK)
  - ...*other fields*...

Disadvantages: Possible integrity issue where blog has no or multiple primary urls.

Advantages: Similar relationship structure for many or one.

**Option 2 - HAS_MANY and BELONGS_TO hybrid**

- url

  - id (PK)
  - url (UNIQUE)
  - blog_id (FK to blog - id)
- blog

  - id (PK)
  - url_id (FK to primary url - id)
  - ...*other_fields*...

Disadvantages: Possible integrity issue where blog's url_id and url's blog_id doesn't match.

Advantages: Guaranteed one primary url per blog.

---

Does anyone have any experience with either of these options, or can think of any other reason to use/discount one or the other? Or possibly a better third option?

**UPDATE**

Just realised that Option 2 renders INSERTs impossible without allowing NULL in either the url's blog_id or blog's url_id.

Comment: What is `primary_flag` for?

Comment: @RickJames To indicate the current active URL, maybe a confusing term to choose.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the above, I'd consider something like this:

- blog

  - id
  - url_id
- url

  - id
  - url
  - redirect_url_id

In this case, the redirect_url_id is a self-referntial foreign key from the url table to itself. If a URL needs to redirect, you'd put the ID of the URL it needed to redirect to in this column.

This would avoid the disadvantages you've noted about the two options you've listed. The only downside is that for primary URLs you'll just need to leave redirect_url_id as a NULL, but this is acceptable.

Definitely avoid Option 2 whatever you do, keys in both directions is - as you've noticed - not workable.

Comment: A couple of potential downsides over Option 1.. 1. The url of the blog could potentially redirect to another blog's url.  2. Adding a new url involves operations on both tables (or a complicated select to find the primary url for a blog).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, a Blog usually has a URL, and it might change over time.  You want to keep the old URL around, and redirect it.  That could happen a few times, and there could be several old URLs.  Sometimes a blog has no active URL, but it never has two.

Let's start with Blog, then, because that's the thing we care about.

```
create table blog
( id  ... primary key
, url ... unique
);
```

Now capture the old URLs:

```
create table url
( blog_id ...
, url ... 
, primary key (blog_id, url)
, foreign key (blog_id) references blog(id)
);
```

if `blog.url` has to be NULL, that's OK.  You'll just have to deal with the possibility that, when you join url to blog, you may get a NULL url to redirect to.  A perfect opportunity to use `coalesce`.  ;-)

In your design, `url.id` serves no real purpose as far as I can tell.  A blog is different from its URL, so an ID is probably needed.  Old URLs, OTHO, only ever belong to the blog they used to belong to.  Giving them an ID just gives you another number to drag around.

Comment: Thanks, some excellent points, but a few extra things. 1. I really wanted all the URLs in one table so I can ensure that a old redirect URL isn't also an active URL for a different blog (I could use a UNION query before insert however). 2. I'm not sure I like the idea of a blog's URL being NULL and having inactive redirects.. I guess I could 404 them, but then why keep them. 3. The extra id isn't necessary, but aids interaction with the framework that we are using.

Comment: You pay a price either way: With all URLs in one table, you have to maintain a current/archived flag, or a priority value (and use e.g. max(priority) for current). Reads being more frequent than writes, I'd keep the URL with its blog.  A trigger could ensure no archived URL is also active. Keep the archived urls even if the current is NULL for the day when the current is not NULL.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

As there doesn't seem to any additional data concerning URL, why place it in a separate table?

```
table blog
  id (PK)
  url (unique)
  ...other_fields..
```

However, the URL data is subject to change and you want to track those changes over time. Great, now you have a reason to move it to a separate table:

```
table blog
  id (PK)
  ...other_fields..

table URLs
  blogID
  url
  EffDate
  Primary key( blogID, url, EffDate )
```

To display blog data with current url:

```
select  b.ID, u.url, b.* -- the other fields
from    blog b
join    URLs u
    on  u.blogID = b.ID
    and u.EffDate = (
          select  Max( EffDate )
          from    URLs u2
          where   ur.blogID = b.ID
              and ur.EffDate <= @today )
where   b.ID = @MyblogID;
```

The nice thing about this query is that to see what the URL was for any particular date in the past, simply replace `@today` with the date you are interested in.

As your app will probably be interested mostly with current URLs, create a view using the query without the `where` clause. For current URLs then, the query would be:

```
select  *
from    Current_blogs
where   ID = @MyblogID;
```